# Deriving the conditions for differentiability if we know that the primary condition is the existence of tangent plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Our professor said that the necessary and sufficient condition to
>   check derivability for a function $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ at a point
>   $(a,b)$ is **either** of the following:
>
> - $\exists$ a function $\epsilon$ such that $f(a+h,b+k)=f(a,b)+l \epsilon(l) + Al$, where $l=\sqrt{h^2+k^2}$ and $\epsilon(l)\to 0$ as
>     $l\to 0$. ($A$ is a constant)
> - $f(a+h,b+k)=f(a,b)+Ah+Bk+h\phi(h,k)+k\psi(h,k)$ where $A,B$ are constants independent of $h,k$ and $\phi,\psi\to0$ as $(h,k)\to(0,0)$.

I'm not sure from where he came up with these two conditions.

I know that for derivative of $f(x,y)$ to exist at the point $(a,b)$, **the tangent plane must exist at that point**. Given we know this much, how can we derive the two conditions quoted above?

Comment: $A$ is a constant in the first condition?

Comment: @zhw. Yes. It is

Comment: What is your definition of the tangent plane existing?

Comment: @zhw. The Jacobian matrix exists...

Comment: That just says the partial derivatives exist. That doesn't even give continuity.

Comment: @zhw. I think that combined with continuity of the partial derivatives at that point suffices.

Comment: Sure, but then you are assuming something stronger than differentiability.

Comment: Partials being continuous is enough to guarantee that the Jacobian is the derivative. I'm not sure if that is a stronger condition that derivability. @zhw.

Comment: Let $f(x,y)=x^2\sin(1/x), x\ne 0, f(0,y)=0.$ Then $f$ is differentiable everywhere, but $\partial f/ \partial x$ is not continuous at any $(0,y).$

Comment: @zhw. Okay, then what is the necessary and sufficient condition according to you (for tangent plane to exist) ?

Comment: Remember I was asking you. I haven't seen the definition other than that $f$ be differentiable at the point in question.

Comment: @zhw. You mean iff a function is differentiable at a point then the tangent plane exists at that point.Then, what is the necessary and sufficient condition for differentiability according to you?

Comment: The standard definition for differentiability at $(a,b)$ is that there exists a linear transformation $T:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ such that $f(a+h,b+k) = f(a,b) + T(h,k) + o[(h^2+k^2)^{1/2}]$ as $(h,k) \to (0,0).$ This is equivalent to your second condition, although it does require a little work to see it.

Comment: Your professor has a problem. The first condition is manifestly wrong. The second is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly the first condition is not equivalent to $f$ being differentiable at $(a,b).$ Let $(a,b) = (0,0)$ and take $f(x,y) = (x^2 + y^2)^{1/2}.$ Then we have the first condition holding with $\epsilon(l) \equiv 0$ and $A=1.$ But $f(x,0)=|x|,$ which implies $\partial f/\partial x(0,0)$ doesn't exist. That implies $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0).$

Answer (score 0):

Forget for a second about $$f(a+h,b+k)=f(a,b)+Ah+Bk+h\phi(h,k)+k\psi(h,k)$$ and take a look at this expression: $$z(h,k)=f(a+h,b+k)=f(a,b)+Ah+Bk$$

Here, $h$ and $k$ change and $a$ and $b$ are fixed numbers.

You can see that $z(h,k)$ is linear function of two variables (because $f(a,b)$ and $A$ and $B$ are all constants), it is an equation of a plane that goes through point $(h,k,f(a+h,b+k))$.

Now, you can see that functions $h\phi(h,k)$ and $k\psi(h,k)$ must tend to $(0,0)$ as $(h,k) \to 0$ if you want for a tangent plane to exist because if they do not tend to $(0,0)$ then we have $h\phi(h,k) \to w \in \mathbb R$ and $k\psi(h,k) \to q \in \mathbb R$ when $(h,k) \to (0,0)$, so in the limit we would get $f(a,b) \neq f(a,b)$ if $q+w \neq 0$, and some analysis should show that we must have $q=w=0$ in order for tangent plane to exist.

If $h$ is fixed then you get $y_1(k)=z(h,k)=f(a,b)+Ah+Bk$ and this is equation of a straight line because only $k$ varies and it varies linearly. If you take a derivative of this linear function you obtain that it equals $B$ and so $B$ is a partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $k$. Then, of course $A$ is partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $h$ because it is derivative of linear function $y_2(h)=z(h,k)=f(a,b)+Ah+Bk$.

So $A$ represents slope of straight line that goes through $(0,0,f(a,b))$ and $B$ represents slope of another straight line that goes through that point (those lines have special directions with respect to $hk$-plane, you should know that they cannot go to infinity in whatever direction we choose) .

Because these two lines intersect at a point they determine unique plane and that is our tangent plane. This is an approach where we suppose that tangent plane exists and then give an explanation of what partial derivatives have to do with her.

So, if a tangent plane exists then $A$ and $B$ must exist, but surely that is not enough for differentiability since there exist functions that have discontinous derivative.